# How to fetch data while the column names are in arabic on sql server?

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, arabic

I have been trying to fetch data from a table with Arabic column names. I was able to convert the Arabic text to utf-8 from other table but I am unable to fetch the data from the table with the Arabic column names.

This is for Linux server, MySql 5,PHP 5 and Apache 2.
I am using PHP MSSQL library to connect to the SQL server.
I have tried querying in Arabic as in `select * from table_name",select رقم الطالب from table_name`

```
ini_set('mssql.charset', 'UTF-8');
header('Content-type:text/html');
echo '<meta charset="UTF-8">';
// Connect to MSSQL
$con = mssql_connect('server', 'username', 'pwd');


if (!$con) {
    die('Something went wrong while connecting to MSSQL');
}

// Select a database:
mssql_select_db('database_name') or die('Could not select a database.');

$SQL = "SELECT `الجنس` as Gender FROM `table_name`";

$result = mssql_query($SQL)  or die('A error occured: ' . mysql_error());

$res=mssql_fetch_assoc($result);

echo iconv('UTF-16LE', 'UTF-8', $Row['Gender']);
```

These are the errors i am facing while trying above method

Warning:

> mssql_query(): message: Incorrect syntax near '`'. (severity 15)

Comment: This is not the reason for your error, but `mysql_error()` should be `mssql_get_last_message()`.

Comment: Thank you man , i didn't notice i was trying different methods trying to solve the issue.

Comment: Are you sure that you use the correct functions - `mssql_` are for MS SQL Server, `mysqli_` are for MySQL Server. Both servers are different, you say that you use MySQL, your `SELECT` statement uses MySQL syntax, but you use `mssql_` functions, which in this case is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you are using sql server or mysql. Assuming sql server, When you have special characters as column names you have to wrap the name in square brackets. If at all possible I would avoid using arabic for column names. It is difficult to work with. I would suggest using english column names (especially since the rest of t-sql is english). Then use arabic in the presentation layer.

```
SELECT [الجنس] as Gender FROM table_name
```

Comment: Thank you for response Sean, i am working with PHP,Mysql and the client database is in SQL Server.
Sadly the table given to me is with arabic names and i cannot ask them to give the alias name in english.

SELECT [الجنس] as Gender FROM table;

I am receiving the error as invalid column name
A error occured: Invalid column name 'ê??èê³?èë??'.

Answer (score 0):

Error message complain about ` and using ` to wrap columns will not work on SQL Server. You need to use double quotes " or brackets.
Also I would recommend to create views with easier to use names for all tables with Arabic column names.

Comment: Thanks for your response Piotr.

Used as you suggested bro no luck,its throwing error as invalid column

A error occured: Invalid column name 'ê??èê³?èë??'

Comment: Looks like issues with encoding in a driver. Can you create views in the database with English names? Then the driver should have no problems with accessing these views.

Comment: I have no permission to create view :(

Comment: what is happening when you run SELECT * from a table?

Comment: I finally got it changed from their end,thanks for all your help.